# Android - A strange artifact in full screen on some devices

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, android-statusbar, android-fullscreen

When running on Android 10 emulator and Galaxy S8 physical device (running Android 9), the next code works perfectly fine. Nevertheless, on Motorola Moto G8 (running Android 9) entering full screen mode, all view's content goes down and in place of status bar blank black space appears.

Galaxy G8, normal and full screen views:

[image: Galaxy, normal mode]
[image: Galaxy, full screen]

Motorola Moto G8, normal and full screen views:

[image: Moto, normal]
[image: Moto, full screen]

As you can see, on motorola g8 screen goes down the size of status bar and on top of screen appears blank black screen.

[image: Moto, artifact]

Here is Android manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

Here's `styles.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <!--Required Api 21 above-->
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:src="@drawable/llama" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean isFullScreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }

        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
                (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                        // Note that system bars will only be "visible" if none of the
                        // LOW_PROFILE, HIDE_NAVIGATION, or FULLSCREEN flags are set.
                        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                            // TODO: The system bars are visible. Make any desired
                            // adjustments to your UI, such as showing the action bar or
                            // other navigational controls.
                            isFullScreen = false;
                        } else {
                            // TODO: The system bars are NOT visible. Make any desired
                            // adjustments to your UI, such as hiding the action bar or
                            // other navigational controls.
                            isFullScreen = true;
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    // onWindowFocusChanged()

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        if (isFullScreen) {
            showSystemUI();
        } else {
            hideSystemUI();
        }
    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        // Enables regular immersive mode.
        // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
        // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                        // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    // Shows the system bars by removing all the flags
// except for the ones that make the content appear under the system bars.
    private void showSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

The whole project is available at Github: https://github.com/alecpetrosky/Android-Immerse-Demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add below code after function setContentView

```
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
 
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
          }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved the problem. I'll give you credits on Demo's project.

Comment: Thank you. I'm waiting